# ExpressJS Render Path with Hash

Tags: node.js, express

How can I set a url such as `localhost:8080/foo#specialStuffHere` from my ExpressJS application? I am using code in my router such as:

```
app.get('/foo/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('foo', {myData: data});
});
```

Comment: URL does not render. Only a view can render. As per your code, you are rendering foo view with some data. So what is your question?

Comment: And also, you can not get the value of any Macro (# value) on server side code, these are meant for client side only. (var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);)

Comment: Sorry for my terminology - I would like to somehow set the value after the # in the URL from my express app.

Comment: question is still not clear. by clicking on some link you want to make #url or what? And also, do you want the value after # also on server side?

Comment: As I am rendering a page (from my express app) I would like to add a # value to the url. I don't need to know the value later on the server side, only in some jQuery in the HTML of the page.

Comment: @mbacvanski I have the exact same problem, I was wondering if you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the command `res.redirect(your url here)` instead of `res.render()`.